# How to clear or stop net-snmpd.log?

Tags: logging, gentoo, snmpd

System: 3.10.17-gentoo

NET-SNMP version:  5.7.3.pre5

ps ax: /usr/sbin/snmpd -p /var/run/snmpd.pid

/etc/conf.d/snmpd: `#SNMPD_FLAGS="${SNMPD_FLAGS} -Lsd -Lf /dev/null"`

/var/log/net-snmpd.log:

```
Connection from UDP: 
Connection from UDP:
Connection from UDP:
```

My net-snmpd log around 600 Mb
If im trying to `echo "" > /var/log/net-snmpd.log`
file becomes 0 Mb, and after a few minutes again 600

I found some manuals, but my config files has different content.
How can i clear log file correctly or stop it?

Comment: Did my answer work? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the "#" from that line in /etc/conf.d/snmpd, then restart snmpd. :) However, that will send output from snmpd to /dev/null, and use syslog for logging.

If you wish to disable *all* logging,  or at least not have it sent somewhere you'd see it, something like this should suffice instead of that line you have:

```
SNMPD_FLAGS="${SNMPD_FLAGS} -Lf /dev/null" # note we've removed the syslog option
```

Good luck!